How is HttpClient injected into a ctor?
I found this ctor:
public class MobileOtpService : IMobileOptService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MobileOtpService(HttpClient client) // How is this injected?
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IMobileOptService, MobileOtpService>();
        ...
        services.AddHttpClient();
    }
}

I can't find any hard-coded instantiations of MobileOtpService, so it must just be using DI.
How is the HttpClient injected?
Does this happen automatically because of services.AddHttpClient()?
I can't find any code that sets the BaseAddress etc.

"I can't find any code that sets the BaseAddress etc." Why does the framework need to set it? It requires you to pass a configuration delegate to AddHttpClient to configure clients.

Sourcecode for AddHttpClient: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Might want to check out Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core which explains how to set up "named" and typed HttpClient - which also includes being able to configuratively set up things like base addresses and default headers and so forth

There are many ways to register and use HttpClients. Let me list here the options:
Default client
This option can be used to get an HttpClient with default settings.
Registration
services.AddHttpClient();

Usage
private readonly HttpClient uniqueClient;
public XYZService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
  => uniqueClient = clientFactory.CreateClient();

Named client
This option can be used to get a preset HttpClient.
Registration
services.AddHttpClient("UniqueName", client => client.BaseAdress = ...);

Usage
private readonly HttpClient uniqueClient;
public XYZService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
  => uniqueClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("UniqueName");

Typed client
This option can be used to wrap a default/preset HttpClient into a higher-level abstraction.
Registration
services.AddHttpClient<UniqueClient>();
services.AddHttpClient<IUniqueClient, UniqueClient>(client => client.BaseAdress = ...);

Usage
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
public UniqueClient(HttpClient client)
  => httpClient = client;

private readonly IUniqueClient uniqueClient;
public XYZService(IUniqueClient client)
  => uniqueClient = client;

Named and Typed client
This option can be used to register different preset HttpClients and wrap them into a higher-level abstraction.
Registration
services.AddHttpClient<IUniqueClient, UniqueClient>("primary", client => client.BaseAdress = ...);
services.AddHttpClient<IUniqueClient, UniqueClient>("secondary", client => client.BaseAdress = ...);

Usage
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
public UniqueClient(HttpClient client)
  => httpClient = client;

public XYZService(
   IHttpClientFactory namedClientFactory, 
   ITypedHttpClientFactory<UniqueClient> namedTypedClientFactory)
{
    var namedClient = namedClientFactory.CreateClient("primary");
    var namedTypedClient = namedTypedClientFactory.CreateClient(namedClient);
}

If you are interested about their lifecycle management then please check out this SO topic.

When you use services.AddHttpClient(); in the extension method you will see that they add the default HttpClient like this:
 // Register default client as HttpClient
            services.TryAddTransient(s =>
            {
                return s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(string.Empty);
            });

For your registration of MobileOtpService I would suggest using extension method AddHttpClient like this:
services.AddHttpClient<IMobileOtpService,MobileOtpService>(httpClient => 
{
  httpclient.BaseAddress = "localhost"
  // add other httpclient config here
});

